# Access: Text is truncated in display of a textbox with Can Grow=Yes in report

Tags: ms-access, vba, textbox

I have two textboxes arranged one immediately above another in the detail area of an Access 2010 report. They both have `Can Grow` set to `Yes`, as does the detail area itself.

When *both* textboxes have had to grow to accommodate their contents, and the text in the bottom textbox is long, its text gets truncated. How can I address this?

Comment: I do not believe this is a programming question, so I reckon you would be better off asking on superuser.com

Comment: @Remou: agree, although arguably a solution would involve programming; indeed, that's the direction I've since gone it seeking to resolve this. I've added a vba tag in hopes that it attracts the right users, but let me know if you still think it should be migrated.

Comment: There is now an entry regarding this bug on the Access uservoice forum. [Please go there and vote](https://access.uservoice.com/forums/319956-access-desktop/suggestions/13478700-stop-randomly-omitting-text-in-reports) if you suffer from this bug and want to get it fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is a known bug. It's based on the font and printer. [Another user claimed that switching to Arial fixed the problem](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-access/access-2010-truncation-of-calibri-rich-text-in/8b6242b3-4a8b-4553-969c-42b0ca709849). His issue was with the **Calibri** font, while mine was with the **Tahoma** font.

My experience was that it depended on the printer as well, as my client would get this bug with one printer, but not another, using the same computer.

Switching to the **Arial** font worked for both of us. Except for the testing already mentioned here, there's no list that I can find of which fonts are buggy and which ones work.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Turns out I am the "other user" in your linked item above, and had neglected to propagate my subsequent learning that the problem doesn't occur for Arial font back to this post or the super user one. Thanks for linking it all up. Are you having the same issue?

Comment: Yes, but haven't been able to test it yet. The bug only shows up with some printers, mine not being one of them. I know it's not an installation issue, because my client has 2 printers where one works, and the other doesn't. I've changed the font to Arial (was using Tacoma), and will test it tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

Is the format of your text boxes by any chance set to `Rich Text`?

If yes, [this is a known bug](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/accessdev/thread/648dd3a2-28c1-4f0d-853c-ef932c58519f). So far, the only workaround we have found is to avoid rich text in reports. Text already stored as rich text in the database can be converted to plain text by using the [PlainText method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb224580.aspx) (i.e., set the ControlSource to `=PlainText([field])`).

We are suffering from this issue as well, so if you found any other workaround or solution, please drop me a comment.

Comment: thanks. Yes it is rich text. I think what I'm experiencing is slightly different but likely to be related to the same underlying problem. I have found that using Access x64 does not have this problem, so my workaround at present is running reports in a VM running Acces x64. Obviously not a scalable solution, but fortunately in my circumstances it is adequate. Obviously I'm keen to hear of any fixes etc.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all suggestions I could find here and elsewhere:  changing fonts, printers, verified PlainText, etc. But nothing fixed this issue.

Here's what finally worked for me:

- Open the report to the Print Preview view.
- Click on Page Setup on the ribbon.
- Click the Columns tab in the Page Setup window.
- In the Column Size section, click the Same as Detail box.

Comment: Wow, hello from 7 years ago!! What’s the future like?

Comment: @sasfrog did you ever find a reliable solution? Rich Text, textboxes with a lot of data do not 'paginate' properly in Access 365 (latest version as of June 14, 2022.)